# How to terminate a program/script by it's name?

Tags: linux, bash

I looked around, and none of the solutions worked for me.
I want to terminate a perl script using the command line.

For example:

```
killall myscript.pl
```

I'm looking for a solution similar to this, all help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: why doesn't killall work? what's the output? can you show the process you wish to kill with `ps`?

Comment: Perhaps use `pkill` .....

Answer (score 4):

You can try pkill, which is a standard on most of today's distributions.

Eg.

```
pkill -f myscript.pl
```

If you want a more portable solution, then you can grep for the name, extract the PID, and kill:

```
kill $(ps xa | grep [m]yscript | awk '{ print $1; exit }')
```

Comment: I don't think that will work because `ps` will see `perl /my/path/myscript.pl`

Comment: Just tried this. Doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: You can always use the -f switch, i've edited the original answer. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8987037/how-to-kill-all-processes-with-a-given-partial-name

Comment: I would like to call out a subtle bit of unstated cleverness in @tvm's answer: `grep [m]yscript`. The square brackets are the clever bit. Having a character class that consists of a single character is functionally the same as if you left the brackets out, as far as the regex itself is concerned. BUT: without that, you would actually get *two* hits from `ps` - the one you want AND the call to grep itself. With the square brackets, the grep call doesn't match, because it has some *literal* square brackets, so it would match `\[m\]yscript`, but not `[m]yscript`.

Answer (score 2):

In perl, assigning to the variable `$0` should change the name of the process listing.  This will affect the output of the `ps` command, on which `killall` and `pkill` rely.

`killall myscript.pl` won't work without the extra `-f` argument @tvm suggested because the script is running within another program (the perl interpreter) so the process will be listed as `perl /path/to/myscript.pl`

You could try `pkill perl` but that will kill all perl interpreters that the current user has permission to kill so it could be dangerous.

The best way to go about this programmatically is to modify the name of the process by assigning to the `$0` variable

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
$0 = 'myscript';
sleep 60;
```

... and then in a standard unix shell:

```
$pkill -9 myscript
```

See [Dynamically name processes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19220001/dynamically-name-processes/19223919#19223919) for more info.